# Strange click and hard disk pause when laptop held at angle

Tags: hard-drive, sony-vaio, clicking-sound

I've noticed that when I carefully rearrange my Sony VAIO Fit 15 in bed while holding it at a very specific angle, an audible click comes from withing the casing. I also noticed that while watching a video from my hard disk, the video would momentarily pause about 1 second later.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be VAIO's Hard Disk Protection function springing into action. It's designed to detect a free fall and prevent permanent damage to your hard disk on impact, but it seems a bit over sensitive.

You don't need to worry about it, but if you're bothered by the hard disk pausing, you can disable the feature in the VAIO Control Center, under the "Hardware" options.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend disabling that. The feature exists to prevent horrible damage and file loss - so the inconvenience is worth it.